# bash function returns with changed indexes

Tags: arrays, bash

I have following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
function getSlots {
    declare -A slots
    for index in `seq 7 10`;
    do
        slots[$index]=$index
    done
    echo ${slots[@]}
}

slots=($(getSlots))

for i in ${!slots[@]};
do
    echo "$i ${slots[$i]}"
done
```

When I run, my output is this:

```
0 10
1 7
2 8
3 9
```

Why do indexes change when I call the function?

Comment: You mean why it's not `10 10, 7 7, ...` or why the values are not in order?

Answer (score 2):

`arr=(...)` re-indexes the array.

With your current approach, you cannot preserve the indexes as any information about them is lost as soon as you leave the function (you just `echo` the values).

You can use [`nameref`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html) (requires `bash` 4.3 or later) to modify the supplied array directly and since you are using only numbers as indexes, regular array will suffice:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function get_slots {
    local index                    # makes index local
    local -n _arr=$1               # _arr points to the supplied array
    _arr=()                        # empties the array
    for index in {7..10}; do
        _arr[index]=$index         # assigns new values to the array
    done
}

get_slots slots

for i in "${!slots[@]}"; do
    echo "$i ${slots[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Tks.. My bash is 4.3.48

Answer (score 1):

Because the `echo ${slots[@]}` at the end of the function `getSlots` expands to `echo 10 7 8 9` and that output is what you are assigning to the array `slots` by doing:

```
slots=($(getSlots))
```

---

Another interesting question would be why `echo ${slots[@]}` expands to `echo 10 7 8 9` and not to `echo 7 8 9 10`.

That is because the `slots` inside `getSlots` is declared as an *associative array*, not an array, i.e.:

```
declare -A slots
```

Replace the line above with:

```
declare -a slots
```

and you will get the following output:

```
0 7
1 8
2 9
3 10
```

Comment: So, the problem is not de 10 7 8 9 values of array, I need to keep the indices when I call the function.